# Can't select option in optionmenu tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

In brief, whenever I attempt to use:

```
import tkinter

def donothing():
    print("Doing nothing")

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    list = ["x", "y", "z"]
    var = tkinter.StringVar()
    var.set("This one doesn't.")
    option = tkinter.OptionMenu(window, var, *list)
    option.grid(row=1, column=1)
    window.mainloop()

main = tkinter.Tk()
var2 = tkinter.StringVar()
var2.set("This one works.")
list2 = ["x","y","z"]
button = tkinter.Button(text="test", command=donothing)
menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(main, var2, *list2)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
menu.grid(row=2, column=1)
main.mainloop()
```

My question is, why doesn't this work? Also, how can I make this work?

As you can see, the one outside the function works fine, but the one inside doesn't. I have plans to use something like this is a much bigger piece of software, so help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is that weird "-> object"

Comment: Pycharm suggested that I add it. The code works fine without it, however. I have now got rid of it, as it is not needed. @user1767754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two instances of `Tk`, and you shouldn't call `mainloop` twice. If you need a second window you need to use an instance of `Toplevel`. If you need for the program to wait for that second window to be destroyed you can use the [wait_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method) method.

For example:

```
import tkinter

def donothing():
    print("Doing nothing")

    window = tkinter.Toplevel()
    list = ["x", "y", "z"]
    var = tkinter.StringVar()
    var.set("This one doesn't.")
    option = tkinter.OptionMenu(window, var, *list)
    option.grid(row=1, column=1)
    print("waiting for the window to go away...")
    main.wait_window(window)
    print("done!")

main = tkinter.Tk()
var2 = tkinter.StringVar()
var2.set("This one works.")
list2 = ["x","y","z"]
button = tkinter.Button(text="test", command=donothing)
menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(main, var2, *list2)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
menu.grid(row=2, column=1)
main.mainloop()
```

For more information about creating temporary dialogs, see [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) on the effbot site.

Comment: Can you please supply something telling me how to do this? Or give me a link to a post explaining it?